# SSRS: No Data Returned when Date Prompts used

Tags: reporting-services

If I use this in my dataset SQL:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate   DATE = '2018-03-01'
```

The report runs and returns the expected Data.

When I comment out the @StartDate & @EndDate variables - delete the two parameters from the Report - and run the report using Date Prompts at run time [using the same Dates] - I get no data returned.

The Date field that I am attempting to filter on is a Datetime field.

I have tried the following two approaches in my SQL:

```
o.ORDERDATE >= @StartDate And o.ORDERDATE <= @EndDate
cast(o.ORDERDATE as DATE) >= Cast(@StartDate As Date) And cast(o.ORDERDATE as DATE) <= Cast(@EndDate As Date)
```

No data.

I added a Text Box to the Report Header and put the @StartDate Parameter value in there and got this: 01/01/2018 12:00:00 AM at run time.

I have gone back and forth a few times between uncommenting and commenting the Date variables at the top of the SQL. When I use the local variables - I get data. When I use the Date Parameters - no data.

I use Date Prompts in many of my other reports with no problems. I will go back and see if any of them is on this particular table and this particular date field - or if any of the other dates are Datetime fields ....

Meanwhile, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume your parameter names are `StartDate` and `EndDate` ?.. According to your query, the names can't have spaces in them.

Comment: @BJones: Yes. No spaces.

Comment: It might be helpful to post your whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect a conversion issue comparing Date and DateTime types. To prove this, set the dates manually in your query to the full date and time. if this produces no results then try something simple like.

```
WHERE CAST(o.ORDERDATE AS Date) Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Bear in mind that if you start your date with the year (I think) by default this is interpreted as being in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "set the dates manually in your query to the full date and time.". Which dates are you suggesting I set to the full date and time? Thanks!

Comment: The moment, when you test, you set the date to '2018-01-01' for example. Set it to '2018-01-01 12:00:00' or whatever the full date and time is at the time of execution. This will only prove the date time conversions are or are not working as you expected. Did you try the suggested change to your code? What were the results?

Comment: I just tried changing the date parameters in SQL Server Management Studio to: ... StartDate Date = '2018-04-02 12:00:00'  
Declare EndDate Date = '2018-04-06 12:00:00'  ... and the query still runs fine. [... I can't use the 'at' symbol in the comments window].

Comment: In SSMS, I also tried setting the Date range to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss ... AND ... using CAST(o.ORDERDATE AS Date). The query still runs fine in SSMS. I'll try CAST(o.ORDERDATE AS Date) in SSRS and let you know. Again, Thanks!

Comment: I thought your suggestion to CAST(o.ORDERDATE As Date) solved my problem. However, when I did that, and I started getting data when using the prompts ... because it made no sense to me whatsoever - I tried changing the SQL back to what it was previously - and it still worked. So now, it is working with OR without the CAST(... As Date). It's almost like a switch was tripped in SSRS and now it is 'untripped' and everything is working like it should. I'd LIKE to mark your suggestion as the answer - but I don't know how accurate that would be. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It could also be dependent on the dates you are using. So 2018-01-01 will always be interpreted as 1st Jan 2018 but 2018-03-01 could be 1st March 2018 or 3rd January 2018 depending on the locale/datetime settings. So check the your datetime setting s have not been changed and try again with the same data and same dates until you find a pattern. Bear in mins that the dates may not be being used as you would expect (as per my comments just now). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!! I just ran into another scenario where I was having a similar phenomenon - but in SSMS - in a T-SQL query. Once I Cast the Datetime field as Date, it worked. I am now pretty certain that your suggestion was the solution and I am marking it as such. Thanks!!